# VSCode issue with setting python version to 3.10 on Azure function sample

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-function-async

I am trying to run the Azure python function with Fast API locally and hit into this issue

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/issues/7

The last one suggests upgrading to the 3.10 version of python to solve the issue. However when i try to upgrade in vs code , i get the errors below

[image]

When i try to manually add the path

[image]

I am not that familiar with all python ENV setups, any suggestions will be helpful

EDIT:

Yes, Here are all the versions I have on the machine

[image]

Comment: That version of python must first exist on your computer, before you can select it as the interpreter in vs code.  Did you install Python 3.10.8 on your computer?

Comment: Added it to the Edit above.

Comment: Hmm. Python 3.10.8 is fairly new; perhaps vs code itself does not know about that version?  Is there an update available for vs code?

Comment: I am on the latest Date: 2022-11-09T02:08:38.961Z (1 wk ago)

Comment: So what is your question? How is the virtual environment created? What are your steps? Can it be created directly using python commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the python versions installed in my windows system:
[image]

When creating the Azure Function Python App in the VS code, it is not showing the Python 3.10.x version interpreter:

[image]

In this step, click on Skip virtual environment and create the required trigger function.

You can select the Python 3.10.x version interpret after creating the trigger function:

[image]

```
py -m pip install --user virtualenv
py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate
py -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Run the above cmdlets to activate virtual environment taken, taken from the Python Packages [Source](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/).

So that you can be able to see the current python version for the current Azure Function in VS Code:

[image]